# Constraining a back wheel to the front wheel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, collision-detection

Hopefully I can describe my situation clearly as whenever I try to describe it to others on the whiteboard or pen and paper it takes a few attempts :)

Part of my program involves a cart that rides along a rail and the cart runs on two wheels. The rails is a simple line which hills up and down in curves and also flattens out. To create the level I use an NSMutableArray of CGPoints and draw them to the screen.

My current collision detection involves using each wheels x-cordinate and comparing it to the array of points x values. When it's between two points x-values I can use the gradient to discover whether or not it's below/under the y-value at that point. This works fine when I use definite values of X.

So here comes the problem.

First, I have a front wheel which rolls along this line perfectly with a correct x and correct y position. The problem I'm having is creating a back wheel that follows this front wheel. The back wheel also follows the line perfectly however it's always a set X distance behind the front wheel, this proves to be unrealistic as when you go up or down steep hills the distance between the wheels is too great due to the difference in Y.

Example:

O.......O

Hill Example:

O

........O

Same distance in x, difference in Y so the hypotenuse distance is greater and gives the impression of the wheels spreading apart. I need to constrain the back wheel to the front wheel so it's true(hypotenuse) distance is always the same. The difficulty I'm having is that since this involves changing it's x-position I can't get a handle on it's collision detection.

If I start to go uphill, I have to change it's y velocity to drop behind the front wheel, so then I need to change it's x-value to stay the same true distance behind the wheel, now it's y-value will be wrong since it ends up in the floor.

Wracked my brains and the offices for a few days now, any help please?

Comment: This may be a good question for the math exchange if you don't get one here. http://math.stackexchange.com/ Sounds like it would be a simple mathematical concept that would do this. IE: cos(hypotenuse)? Something like that, instead of changing Y, you'd be changing the ratio of x:y

Comment: the problem with this is that it only works if the gradient beneath both wheels is the same. If it's on a quick slope it'll result in the backwheel either being above or below the hill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to keep the wheels the same distance apart is to constrain both wheels to the track.  You could define a 3rd number for the NSMutableArray track, distance from track origin.  You'd have to define your own class instead of using the CGPoints class.

Another possibility is to have the center of the wheels follow the track, but with an offset equal to the radius of the wheels.  The center of each wheel is calculated using the track x and y coordinates, the angle of the line from where the wheel touches the track to the center of the wheel, and the radius of the wheel,